# How to group a specific number of blocks in an xml based on number of tags

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a big xml like below and I would like to group a specific number of tags under one block; The expected input and output below will make my question clearer. Any help is greatly appreciated

The input file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Root>
    <ListABC>
        <ABC name="name1" class="class1" age="age1" />
        <ABC name="name2" class="class2" age="age2" />
        <ABC name="name3" class="class3" age="age3" />
        <ABC name="name4" class="class4" age="age4" />
        <ABC name="name5" class="class5" age="age5" />
    </ListABC>
    <ListABC>
        <EOF tag1="1" tag2="2" tag3="3"/>
    </ListABC>
</Root>
```

I need to create a tag **ListABC** after every 2 **ABC** elements and at the same time, the last **ListABC** which contains **EOF** element should not be impacted at all. This is how I need the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Root>
    <ListABC>
        <ABC name="name1" class="class1" age="age1" />
        <ABC name="name2" class="class2" age="age2" />
    </ListABC>
    <ListABC>
        <ABC name="name3" class="class3" age="age3" />
        <ABC name="name4" class="class4" age="age4" />
    </ListABC>
    <ListABC>
        <ABC name="name5" class="class5" age="age5" />
    </ListABC>
    <ListABC>
        <EOF tag1="1" tag2="2" tag3="3"/>
    </ListABC>
</Root>
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="ListABC[not (EOF)]/ABC[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <ListABC>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::ABC[1]"/>
            </ListABC>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ListABC[EOF]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I just tested this and that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much michael. Glad that I was able to explain the question as I wanted. Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: A follow up question. What if I had to group every 4 ABC elements? or every X number of ABC elements?

Comment: I tried position() > 4 and position()  = 4 - But the did not produce the desired output

Comment: I got it worked when i tried this

        <xsl:for-each select="ListABC[not (EOF)]/ABC[position() mod 4 = 1]">
            <ListABC>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::ABC[position() &lt; 4]"/>
            </ListABC>
        </xsl:for-each>